# sonarqube error Unrecognized command line argument: Dsonar.scm.provider=git

Tags: git, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Jenkins executes the sonar commands and it shows the below error, any suggestion why we might get this error?

```
11:17:10.773  Unrecognized command line argument: Dsonar.scm.provider=git
11:17:10.775  Expecting at least the following command line argument:
- SonarQube project key
When connecting to a SonarQube server earlier than version 6.1, the following command line arguments are also required:
- SonarQube project name
- SonarQube project version
The full path to a settings file can also be supplied. If it is not supplied, the exe will attempt to locate a default settings file in the same directory as the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild.
11:17:10.775  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Comment: Please add the command which you executed.

Comment: What version of SonarQube and plugin do you use?

Comment: sonarqube-6.1
sonar-scanner-2.8
sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24

Comment: sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar for git plugin

Answer (score 0):

You should be running:
**SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe** /t:Rebuild

The right way is:
**MSBuild.exe** /t:Rebuild

For mac users:
dotnet build